# How do you put an image inside of an Angular2 Material fab button?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to put an image inside of a fab button in Angular2 Material. 
The look is the look if you are logged in on Google, or in Gmail.

Angular2 Material docs don't have anything yet on this.

For example, see this image: http://www.mattpaulson.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/gmail-zero.png

Code I've been playing with (that doesn't work) is:

```
    <button md-fab 
        type="button">
        <img md-fab-image [src]="userInfo.photoUrl">
        <div class="md-ripple-container"></div>
    </button>

    <button md-fab 
        type="button">
        <img md-fab-image [src]="userInfo.photoUrl">
    </button>

    <button md-fab md-fab-image
        type="button">
        <img md-fab-image [src]="userInfo.photoUrl">
    </button>

    <button md-icon-button
        type="button">
        <img [src]="userInfo.photoUrl">
    </button>

    <button md-icon-button
        md-fab-image
        type="button">
        <img  [src]="userInfo.photoUrl">
    </button>

    <button md-icon-button md-fab-image
        type="button">
        <img md-fab-image [src]="userInfo.photoUrl">
    </button>

    <button md-icon-button md-fab-image
        type="button">
        <img md-fab-image [src]="userInfo.photoUrl">
    </button>
```

### Non-ideal hack

```
    <button md-fab md-button
        style="overflow:hidden;top:1rem;"
        type="button">
        <img [src]="userInfo.photoUrl" style="max-width:100%">
    </button>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use:

> **mat-icon-button**   Circular button with a transparent background, meant to
>   contain an icon

```
<button (click)="onEditBtnClick(row)" mat-icon-button color="accent"> 
    <mat-icon>create</mat-icon>
</button>
```

"create" is an icon from https://material.io/icons/
https://material.angular.io/components/component/button

Answer (score 10):

You can use `button md-fab` with some additional styling.

```
<button md-fab class="image" 
  [style.backgroundImage]="'url(' + YOUR_IMAGE_URL + ')'">
</button>
```

and add:

```
button {
  &.image {
   background-color: transparent;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: cover;
   background-position: center center;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`src` is property not an event

```
<img md-fab-image [src]="userInfo.photoUrl">
```

Comment: I think something wrong in the `userInfo.photoUrl` make sure it holds the correct value.

Comment: I'm just assuming that md-fab-image works... it was from Material1.... Not sure if it exists yet in the latest Material...

Comment: I'm getting an image.. But it is a big fat square. It isn't living inside the fab button. The ripple effect is there, but only on the small circle, not the overlying big square image...

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest with material design md-icon as below, which can be played with material icons

```
<button md-raised-button><md-icon>home</md-icon>Some Button</button>

<button md-fab><md-icon>home</md-icon></button>

<button md-mini-fab><md-icon>list</md-icon></button>
```

Any phrase linked inside `<md-icon>    </md-icon>` is assumed be code for the icon.

Note : The commonly used bootstrap glyphicons, font awesome are in progress.

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/4dUTGRF4SrFrnB2KS08S?p=preview)**

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work as well

```
<button mat-mini-fab 
    style="background: url('../assets/logo.png') center no-repeat>
</button>
```